# python list comprehension products

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to build a specific list comprehension to take data from list of lists/matrix A and matrix B to generate a third matrix, C.  I've annotated the code and provided the expected outcome, but as written, the list comprehension doesn't do what's expected and can can be expressed in more elegant code than I've attempted here.  Xt=transposed matrix X, Xs=sorted matrix X

```
# matrix A with row headings and values
A = [('Apple',0.95,0.99,0.89,0.87,0.93),
('Bear',0.33,0.25.0.85,0.44,0.33),
('Crab',0.55,0.55,0.10,0.43,0.22)]

#matrix B with row headings and values
B = [('Apple',1.00.0.99,1.00,0.95,0.99),
('Bear',0.99,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.99),
('Crab', 0.05,0.19,1.00,0.55,0.89)]

#transpose matrix A and B
At=zip(*A)
Bt=zip(*B)

#generate a new empty matrix, C, and give it the same heading labels as A and B
Ct=At[0:1]

#delete the heading labels on transposed matrices A and B
del At[0]
del Bt[0]

#List Comprehension Code
#multiply all the numbers in row [x] (i.e., apples) for matrix A = apple product A
#multiply all the numbers in row [x] for matrix B = apple product B
#A matrix row [x] product / B matrix row [x] product B = apple value for matrix C
#append apple value under apple heading
#do this for bear rows and crab rows, too
Ct.append((prod(x) for x in zip(*At))/(prod(x) for x in zip(*Bt)))

#untranspose matrix C to match the heading, value configuration of original matrices
C=zip(*Ct)

#sort matrix C rows in descending order based on comprehension [i][1] values
Cs = matrix(sorted(C, key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
```

The final output should look like this for matrix Cs based on current values for matrix A and B:

```
'Apple' 0.7191   #(matrix A apple row product = 0.6696 / matrix B apple row product = 0.9311)
'Crab'  0.6170   #(matrix A crab row product = 0.0029 / matrix B cat row product = 0.0047)
'Bear'  0.0098   #(matrix A bear row product = 0.0093 / matrix B bear row product = 0.9510)
```

Comment: *"Specifically, I want to divide the product of each row (not including the text heading [0]), append that to the matching row of matrix C, then arrange the rows in C in reverse order by their column 1 values."* I would humbly suggest you clarify this, or provide commented pseudocode. Divide the product of each row by what? What are the (relative) sizes of the matrices? etc.

Comment: Also you have not said what the problem you are having with your code is...

Comment: One immediate problem is that the first element of A and B do not start with a left parenthesis.  In addition, you have a decimal point instead of a comma in lines 3 and 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for, might be missing something.

Your posted code is replete with syntax errors and undefined functions.

However, this does what I think you're asking for, but with different results:

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> A = [('Apple',0.95,0.99,0.89,0.87,0.93),('Bear',0.33,0.25,0.85,0.44,0.33),('Crab',0.55,0.55,0.10,0.43,0.22)]
>>> B = [('Apple',1.00,0.99,1.00,0.95,0.99),('Bear',0.99,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.99),('Crab', 0.05,0.19,1.00,0.55,0.89)]
>>> C = [ (a[0],reduce(mul,a[1:])/reduce(mul,b[1:])) for (a,b) in zip(A,B) ]
>>> C
[('Apple', 0.72737272727272728), ('Bear', 0.010706894358222457), ('Crab', 0.6153755174452985)]
```

---

**Additionally**:

*Or what if I just dropped matrix B altogether and C 'Apple' row would equal:

0.95*0.99*0.89*0.87*0.83?*

```
>>> prodA = [ (a[0],reduce(mul,a[1:])) for a in A ]
>>> prodA
[('Apple', 0.67725310950000006), ('Bear', 0.010182150000000001), ('Crab', 0.0028616500000000003)]
```

**And**

*How would I modify this to obtain the product of each row for each A element divided by its paired B element? i.e., the C 'Apple' row would equal:

[('Apple', (0.95/1.00) * (0.99/0.99) * (0.89/1.00) * (0.87/0.95) * (0.93/0.99)]*

```
>>> A_by_B = [ [x[0][0]]+[i/j for (i,j) in x[1:]] for x in [ zip(a,b) for (a,b) in zip(A,B) ]]
>>> A_by_B
[
 ['Apple', 0.94999999999999996, 1.0, 0.89000000000000001, 0.9157894736842106, 0.93939393939393945],
 ['Bear', 0.33333333333333337, 0.25252525252525254, 0.85858585858585856, 0.44444444444444448, 0.33333333333333337],
 ['Crab', 11.0, 2.8947368421052633, 0.10000000000000001, 0.78181818181818175, 0.24719101123595505]
]
>>> prod_A_by_B = [ (x[0],reduce(mul,x[1:])) for x in A_by_B ]
>>> prod_A_by_B
[('Apple', 0.72737272727272728), ('Bear', 0.010706894358222457), ('Crab', 0.61537551744529861)]
```

Each value of each row of A divided by that of B, then the product of each row, is the same as the product of each row of A divided by the product of each row of B.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  How would I modify this to obtain the product of each row for each A element divided by its paired B element?  i.e., the C 'Apple' row would equal [('Apple', (0.95/1.00)*(0.99/0.99)*(0.89/1.00)*(0.87/0.95)*(0.93/0.99)]  MattH's comprehension was exactly what I requested, but when I started playing with the numbers I realized what I requested wasn't the right way to go about it.

Comment: Or what if I just dropped matrix B altogether and C 'Apple' row would equal 0.95*0.99*0.89*0.87*0.83?

Comment: Thank you again.  One last iteration on the theme: how would I get the average of each A row instead of the product?  I tried using mul()/len(), but it didn't work

Comment: Didn't mean to be holding that over your head.  Answer checked.

Comment: Why did you delete the answer to the follow up question which you requested?  It was a simple mistake on my part.  I can average things on my calculator, but not a computer program, apparently.

Comment: The answer was wrong, I had not generated the averages and I'd gone to bed, iPhone not so handy for correcting things like that